# Why Does My Modal Window got Opacity Down along with other Elements When Triggered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, window

I have been working on my client's project, in which I have to include a modal window. The Model window should popup when the link is clicked.
But when the modal window gets triggered, the opacity of all elements decrease **including the modal window**. 
But the Modal window's Opacity should not be decreased by default is nt it ?

This is the HTML code of my modal window:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="background-color: white">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Here is my triggering html code

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
     <div class="block-image-round margin-top-120">
         <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
              <img src="images/banners/1.png" style="width:100%; " alt="">
         </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Modal window part is sibling off the triggering HTML

When The snippet running independently
[image: snippet run independently]

But when the same snippet mentioned here used in my project code 
[image: When Run in my project]

Comment: I saw a similar issue. Try to define `z-index='20000'`: `<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="background-color: white; z-index: 20000;">`

Comment: @Banzay thanks for the reply brother. But it doesn't work .

Comment: could you provide a link to jsFiddle snippet?

Comment: I've also had this before. Placing the modal at the end of your `<body>` tag with the `<body>` being it's parent fixed it for me.

Comment: here https://jsfiddle.net/gjpmjrq7/ it works right

Comment: @Banzay My problem is that When I trigger the modal window, both the modal window opacity and other elements opacity is lowered. By default for modal window its opacity is 1 is nt it ?

Comment: I copypasted your code to jsfiddle and opacity of modal is 1 when it's triggered

Comment: @Banzay I have edited my question. Can you have a look into it :)

Comment: A trivial question: did you declare `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the first line of your project code?

Comment: @Banzay Yeah, I already added.

Comment: could you show full page code here?

Answer (score 0):

Click this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/aEbvvOWGHGQAoLf2ImiF?p=preview) for Example

```
[1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/aEbvvOWGHGQAoLf2ImiF?p=preview
```

Hope this will be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
     <div class="block-image-round margin-top-120">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/200/300" style="width:100%; " alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="background-color: white">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please check my question again. I have editted it.